# Metro Windows 8 WebView, Make it unscrollable

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, webview, microsoft-metro

```
 <WebView  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="90" Width="900" IsHitTestVisible="False"  />
```

Ive also tried to put both scrollmodes displayed, overflow=hidden; on the html and no success. On WP
these properties work just fine. I can make the webview bigger but then there is an issue with the default bounce effect. The Webview has the purpose of showing ads.

any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Are the ads clickable ?